# How to modify a neural network with Keras during training?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

Let's say I have the following inside my network:

```py
x = Conv2D(
            filters=256,
            kernel_size=5,
            strides=2,
            padding="same"
        )(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
```

By the way, I'm working with the Tensorflow backend.

During training, I would like to modify or reduce the value of the Dropout layer. And ultimately, is there any way to deactivate it?

Comment: when do you exactly want to deactivate?

Comment: let's say for the sake of example, once every 2 epochs I want to divide by two the dropout rate. And after 10 epochs I would like to completely disable it

Comment: I can tell you how to do it in tensorflow if that's okay?

Comment: I can try at least, thanks

Comment: You can define a placeholder in tensorflow let's say `keep_prob` which has probability value for dropout. Now, when you train your model, you can change your variable `keep_prob` based on your epoch and update in this line of code - `sess.run(xx ,feed_dict= {x: batchx, ypred :batchy, keep_prob:dropout_rate}`

Comment: check the link for keras:

Comment: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3424

Comment: @talos1904: oh that's very smart and simple :D

Comment: @Padd: thanks for the link! I will try this

Comment: @JonathanDEKHTIAR - I really don't know if that was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found out:

```py
class MyModel():
    def __init__(self, init_dropout, dropout_decay):

        self.init_dropout  = init_dropout
        self.dropout_decay = dropout_decay

        input_layer = Input((64, 64, 1))
        x = Conv2D(
            filters=256,
            kernel_size=5,
            strides=2,
            padding="same"
        )(input_layer)
        x = Dropout(rate=init_dropout)(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
        x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)

        self.model = Model(input_layer, x)

    def decay_dropout(self, epoch, verbose=0):

        rate = max(0, self.init_dropout * (1 / np.exp(self.dropout_decay * epoch))) #define a formula for dropout decay

        for layer in self.model.layers:
            if isinstance(layer, Dropout):

                if (verbose >= 1):
                    print("Decaying Dropout from %.3f to %.3f" % (layer.rate, rate))

                layer.rate = rate
```

And then of course the function decay_dropout needs to be called after each epoch.

Comment: Are you sure that this works? I've tried to use `layer.rate` as well, but in my experiments it doesn't work at all.

For testing this, I've just tried to overfit a nn with few samples. If you set the dropout rate to 0.0 during creating the model (functional API), overfitting the small data sample obviously works.
However, if you create it with a dropout rate of e.g. 0.2 and then try to set it to 0.0 again with `layer.rate`, the net will never overfit.

So for me it seems like `layer.rate` writes the rate to the config, but is never used (compiling after setting the rate doesn't work too).